# how to force renewal of dns cache

Tags: debian, dns

I am using a dynamic dns service which I update via command line. Now my problem is that, after updating the IP, Linux still uses the old IP when trying to access the dyndns-Adress.

How do I force Debian to request updated dns info when I am using ping or Nmap on the dynamic dns address?

Comment: What is the DNS TTL for the dynamic domain name? Maybe it's too big and the Linux system is honouring it correctly

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your local DNS resolver works. In Debian 11 you may try (always as root): 
`/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved --flush-caches`

`resolvectl flush-caches` should do the same. Another way to invalidate systemd's NS cache is: 
`pkill -USR2 systemd-resolved`

If you ary using the Name service caching daemon (nscd), you have to use the command: 
`nscd --invalidate=hosts`

Comment: i get the answers /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved: unrecognized option '--flush-caches'  and  Failed to flush caches: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found..... How do I make a new line in comments ?!

Comment: Then use `resolvectl flush-caches` or the kill command as described above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the XY problem.

What you are asking here (how to force a client to re-fetch DNS records) does not solve the problem (ensuring that the client has the current DNS record) unless you use the authoritative dynamic DNS server as your DNS provider; if you flush the cache on your local machine that does not flush the cache on other DNS servers you may be using.

If your local machine is the only host which needs the DNS records to reflect immediate changes AND you can't control the TTL why not use the hosts file (or an override if your resolver supports it).

If you need to the DNS records to be updated for all clients, and you can't change the TTL, then the DNS service is not fit for your purpose. Use a different one or setup your own.